# How does "true" evaluate in the lazy lambda calculus?

Tags: functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, lambda-calculus

In the lambda calculus, "true" is defined as a function that takes two arguments but returns the first one:

```
true = \x.\y.x
```

What happens if you evaluate this lazily after giving it only one argument?

```
(\x.\y.x a)
```

In either the lazy or eager case it should give

```
\y.a
```

yet this is a function that doesn't even care about it's argument `y`.  So if we're lazy, does it actually resolve to just `a`, without even providing the argument `y`?  Or does it still have to wait for the argument, only it doesn't bother evaluating the argument if it happens to be an expression rather than a simple value?

Comment: `true a` evaluates to `(\x.\y.x) a`, not to `(\x.\y.x a)`

Comment: "*Does it still have to wait for the argument, only it doesn't bother evaluating the argument?*" - yes, exactly that.